# face detection Asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, face-detection

i have implement asp.net web application in this application i add face detection functionality. i have found entire google but did not get solution.

If you have any idea about this solution,please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How will the faces be presented to your application? User upload? Webcam?

Comment: so you want us to write your app?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple actually.

1. Create an ActiveX and Java Applet that will run on your end users workstation it will connect to his Web Cam. and provide your website with a feed.(Like cam in Gmail).
2. Compare existing snapshot of feed with stored images of end users in you database using a face detection algorithm like OpenCVS implementation for C# on your server if match allow them to login to your website.

Comment: Good luck getting users to install an ActiveX! Seriously, Flash would be a better choice here.